# Jquery Ajax request is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to send an jquery ajax request from javascript. I am using the following code for it, but it is not working.

```
$j.ajax({
    url: 'https://c.na14.visual.force.com/apex/controlApi',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success : function(result){
        alert('Result is '+result);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('status is '+jqXHR.status);
        alert('Error is '+textStatus);
    }     
});
```

My response is in json format. Its like

```
{
  "mydata" : "xxxxxxx"
}
```

When I using the above ajax request, the error function gets executed. It shows status is 200 and Error is "parsererror". But, my response in the json format (verified it). So, I am confused with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: If that is the complete response then its not in the right format for [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

JSONP response must be in the following form

```
testCallback({
  "mydata" : "xxxxxx"
})
```

and the request will be

```
$j.ajax({
    url: 'https://c.na14.visual.force.com/apex/controlApi?callback=testCallback',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain : true,
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'testCallback',
    success : function (data){
             alert(data.mydata);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error is '+textStatus);
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You've asked jQuery to use JSON-P, not JSON. JSON-P responses look like this:

```
callback({
  "mydata" : "xxxxxx"
})
```

...where `callback` is the function name specified on the URL of the request. More on [JSON-P here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

If the request is on the [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) as the document making the request, you can use JSON by changing your `dataType` to `"json"`.

If it's on a different origin and that's why you're using JSON-P, you need to modify your server side to extract the name of the function from the URL's query string, and then put the function call into your response as above.